# Android ART VM Remove Data From Properties File

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, virtual-machine, dalvik, art-runtime

Several days ago I changed VM on my Nexus 5 from Dalvik on ART.

I'm developing an application for Android and that application is multi language. So problem is when user chooses a language or changes it. This change was saved in a properties file (SharedPreferences).

But on one of my Activities I have an Image Flipper with several images, `ListView` which is loading data from xml file and in the background the GPS trying to find user location. (GPS is running in a separated thread)

When user enters this Activity, the data is removed from my properties file with saved language. This is happening only on this Activity and only on ART Virtual Machine. It works fine on Dalvik.

Does anybody know what happening?